# Django:- The QR code is being generated successfully, but it is not being saved to the database

Tags: python, django, qr-code, django-signals

I'm using [`qrcode`](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/), a Python library that enables you to generate QR codes. I want to use this Python library inside my Django signals to generate a QR code for every newly created user. However, when the user is created, it doesn't create an `Account` model object, and the QR code is generated inside my project directory, instead of static folder. How can I solve this problem.

signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        random_number = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=20))
        img = qrcode.make('cullize')
        img.save('default.png')
        Account.objects.create(
            user=instance, qr_code=img,
            account_id=random_number
            )
```

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcode')
    account_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: have you registered signal to AppConfig?

Comment: @MadhavDhungana yes. Using `def ready(self): from . import signals` inside  `apps.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, my code is saving the QR code image in the current working directory. To save it in the static folder, I need to construct the path accordingly. I'm using `os.path.join()` to create the correct path for saving the image:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        random_number = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=20))
        
        
        img = qrcode.make('cullize')
        
        # Define the directory where the image should be saved within the 'media' folder
        img_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'qrcode')
        os.makedirs(img_dir, exist_ok=True)  # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        
        # Define the complete path to save the image
        img_path = os.path.join(img_dir, 'default.png')
        
        # Save the QR code image
        img.save(img_path)
        
        Account.objects.create(
            user=instance,
            qr_code=os.path.relpath(img_path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
            account_id=random_number
        )
```

I have updated my `urls.py` to include a URL pattern for serving media files:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I also updated my `settings.py` to include the necessary configurations for media files:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

[**`from a particular source`**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-upload-files-with-filesystemstorage/amp/)

Answer (score 0):

os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,  'qrcode')
I think this will be your static path

Do you want to upload inside static folder or media folder?

Comment: inside a `media` folder so that I can be able to access the image via: `qr_code.url` inside my template. This problem is [`solved here.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000306/21835997)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *not* to generate and store QR codes. Indeed, QR codes take some space while these can easily be generated at (near-) real time. We can construct a view as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76952326/67579):

```
from io import BytesIO

from django.http import HttpResponse
from qrcode import make
from qrcode.image.svg import SvgPathImage


def qr_code_for_account(request, pk):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=pk)
    buffer = BytesIO()
    image = make(f'{account.account_id:020}', image_factory=SvgPathImage)
    image.save(buffer)
    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type='image/svg+xml')
```

this is thus a view that will, for a primary key of an `Account`, generate the corresponding QR code on the fly, and after the view is finished and the SVG is returned, nothing is stored in disk space.

As for generating an `account_id`, you don't need a signal either, you can work with a default callable:

```
def random_account_id():
    return int(''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=20)))


class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # no qr_code
    # important that there are no parenthesis
    account_id = models.IntegerField(
        default=random_account_id, blank=True, editable=False
    )
```

Comment: Where would you like me to use this code, Willem? We want our users to have a QR code so that when someone scans their QR code in the `Transaction` model, they can send them money. Each user should have a unique QR code.

Comment: Secondly, the use of signals is to create a unique QR code for our users. If a user is created, a unique QR code will be generated for them. Users shouldn't create their account_id manually, but automatically.

Comment: @AdamuDeeAzare: the user does not generate the `account_id` (it has `editable=False`), you put the view, whell in `views.py` and you make a `url` that you can then use in a template for example where you *render* the QR code in the template.